# Why does my powershell runspace seem to run sequentially?

Tags: multithreading, powershell, ms-word, hashtable, runspace

I have built a network keyword searcher to assist with my job. I am opening Word documents and inspecting their content for key words. The process took far too long with a classic "for each" file run search. I developed the below code to execute a runspace within a runspace pool, but when this executes it seems to still run sequentially. I am assuming that I have messed up the construction of the runspace pool. I would appreciate any feedback on how to improve this function.

I have already reviewed the following documents but still can't quite seem to find my issue.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/beginning-use-of-powershell-runspaces-part-1/
https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-multithreading/

```
Function getWordMatches ($wordFiles, $TermArray)
{
    #Synchronized Hashtable is need for variable control during runspace execution 
    $dataSync = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
    $dataSync.returns = New-Object -TypeName "System.Collections.ArrayList"

    # Create an empty arraylist that we'll use later
    $Jobs = New-Object -TypeName "System.Collections.ArrayList"

    $maxThreads = Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NumberOfLogicalProcessors

    # Create a Runspace Pool with a minimum and maximum number of run spaces. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd324626(v=vs.85).aspx)
    $RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1,$maxThreads)

    # Open the RunspacePool so we can use it
    $RunspacePool.Open()

    # Define a script block to actually do the work
    $WordScriptBlock = {
        Param($file, $TermArray, $dataSync)

        #Establish Word variables for searching
        $matchCase = $false
        $matchWholeWord = $true
        $matchWildCards = $false
        $matchSoundsLike = $false
        $matchAllWordForms = $false
        $forward = $true
        $wrap = 1
        

        #The below lines open new instances of the MS Word and Excel applications that will be used.
            $check = Test-Path -Path $file -PathType Leaf
            if (-Not $check){return $false}
             
            $Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
            $Word.visible = $False

            #the visible value is set to false so as not to interfere with the user during execution.
            $hash = Get-FileHash $file -Algorithm SHA256 | Select-Object Hash
            try{
                #I needed to add a default password 'ttt' due some password protected files that stopped the script from running    
                $document = $Word.documents.open($file.FullName, 'ReadOnly:=$true', 'AddToRecentFiles:=$false', "PasswordDocument:='ttt'", 'Visible:=$false') 
                $range = $document.content
            }catch{
                $Word.Quit()
            }
            Foreach ($term In $TermArray)
            {
                $wordFound = $range.find.execute($term,$matchCase,$matchWholeWord,$matchWildCards,
                                $matchSoundsLike,$matchAllWordForms,$forward,$wrap)
                If($wordFound)
                    {
                        #Hashtable to store the data for writing the csv output. Stored the data
                        $properties = @{File = $file.FullName; Term_Match = $term; Hash = $hash.Hash}
                        $result = New-Object -TypeName PsCustomObject -Property $properties
                        $dataSync.returns += $result
                        Break
                    }
            }
            $document.close($false)
            $Word.Quit()
    } #/WordScriptBlock
    
      
    # Loop through all word files
    Foreach ($file In $wordFiles)
    {
            $Powershell = [Powershell]::Create().AddScript($WordScriptBlock)
            $Powershell.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
            $Powershell.AddArgument($file).AddArgument($TermArray).addArgument($dataSync) | Out-Null
            $JobObj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                Runspace = $Powershell.BeginInvoke()
                Powershell = $Powershell
                } #/New-Object

            $Jobs.Add($JobObj) | Out-Null #added to a runspace arraylist
     } 

   #cycles through the jobs and will check to see if they are complete. If it is then it will remove the job from the job list.     
    $i = 0
    $total = $Jobs.Count
    while($Jobs){
        Write-Progress -Activity "Processing Word jobs" -Status "$($Jobs.Count) Jobs Remaining" -PercentComplete ($i/$total * 100)
        foreach ($Runspace in $Jobs.ToArray()){
            If ($Runspace.Runspace.IsCompleted) {
                $Runspace.Powershell.Dispose()
                $Jobs.Remove($Runspace)
                $i++
            }
        }
    }
    $wordResults = $dataSync.returns
    return $wordResults
}
```

Comment: I dont see an issue at first glance with your runpsace code logic but, its worth pointing out a few things, you seem to be writing to a word document. Are you sure this is a thread safe operation ? You also are hashing files, I don't think (havent personally tested tho) that hashing files in parallel will give you any edge over sequential operation, and it may be possible that attempting to hash in parallel might be even slower (similar to zipping files in parallel).

Comment: Thanks for the input. It may not be threadsafe. I will check that. I may be using the word object incorrectly. I was just trying to read the document and close it without any changes. The results of the findings should be written to the hashtable. I will run some tests with the hashing.

Comment: You should also note that `[hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})` can be pretty slow. Instead of all threads writing to it, you should make your threads return their results which you can then capture in your main thread, that is certainly faster